# Find all tables that have X column name

Tags: sql, sql-server

Is there a way to find all the tables that have an X column name within the Y database?

So

If X.Column Exists in Y.Database
Print all.tables with x.column

Thanks

Comment: Which database? Each database system stores information about itself differently.

Comment: Please tag your question to identify which brand of database you're using, e.g. [tag:sql-server], [tag:oracle], [tag:mysql], [tag:postgresql], etc.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Most, but not all, databases support the `information_schema` tables.  If so, you can do:

```
select table_name
from information_schema.columns t
where column_name = YOURCOLUMNNAME;
```

If your database doesn't support the `information_schema` views, then any reasonable database has an alternative method for getting this information.

You may need to specify the database name, but that depends on the database.  It could be:

```
select table_name
from YOURDATABASENAME.information_schema.columns t
where column_name = YOURCOLUMNNAME;
```

or

```
select table_name
from YOURDATABASENAME.information_schema.columns t
where column_name = YOURCOLUMNNAME and schema_name = YOURDATABASENAME;
```

Comment: This includes views as well.

Answer (score 2):

For sql server try this...

```
SELECT t.name 
FROM sys.tables t INNER JOIN sys.columns c
ON t.[object_id] = c.[object_id]
WHERE c.name LIKE '%ColumnName%'
```

Answer (score 2):

**In Postgresql** it would simply be:

```
SELECT table_name 
FROM information_schema.columns 
WHERE column_name = 'some_column_name';"
```

**In Mysql**:

```
SELECT DISTINCT table_name 
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE column_name='column'
AND table_schema='database_name';
```

**In MSSQL**:

```
SELECT columns.name AS column, 
t.name AS table
FROM sys.columns columns
JOIN sys.tables t ON columns.object_id = table.object_id
WHERE columns.name = 'column_name';
```

Answer (score 0):

For SQL Server:

```
SELECT t.name AS table_name,
SCHEMA_NAME(schema_id) AS schema_name,
c.name AS column_name
FROM sys.tables AS t
INNER JOIN sys.columns c ON t.OBJECT_ID = c.OBJECT_ID
WHERE c.name LIKE '%YourColumnName%'
ORDER BY schema_name, table_name;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT c.name  AS 'ColumnName' ,t.name AS 'TableName'
FROM sys.columns c
JOIN sys.tables  t   ON c.object_id = t.object_id
WHERE c.name LIKE 'ColoumnName%'
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, including an explanation of *how* and *why* this solves the problem [would really help](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now!  Please [edit] your answer to add explanation, and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Answer (score 0):

Open an editor in your data base and execute this script. Remeber to change 'last_name' for your desired column name.

```
> select t.table_schema,
>        t.table_name from information_schema.tables t inner join information_schema.columns c on c.table_name = t.table_name 
>                                 and c.table_schema = t.table_schema where c.column_name = 'last_name'
>       and t.table_schema not in ('information_schema', 'pg_catalog')
>       and t.table_type = 'BASE TABLE' order by t.table_schema;
```

Thanks to *https://dataedo.com/kb/query/postgresql/find-tables-with-specific-column-name*