# Select all tables that have matching column name

Tags: java, mysql, ucanaccess

Is there a method to select and execute a query on all columns in the database that match a specific name using UCANACESS

I've attempted using methods for MYSQL found at [Find all tables that have X column name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23916540/find-all-tables-that-have-x-column-name)

```
String sql = "SELECT DISTINCT table_name FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE column_name= 'CID'";



        ResultSet rs = readID.executeQuery(sql);
        System.out.println("This plugin has successfully connected to the database...");
        do {
            userInput2 = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"HIPAA Main Menu \n1. Encrypt the database. \n2. Decrypt the database.\n3. Exit the program.\n(Make a selection by entering 1, 2, or 3)");
            choice = Integer.parseInt(userInput2);
            switch (choice) {
                case 1 :
                    while (rs.next()) {
                        ID = rs.getString("CID");
                        rs.updateString("CID", encodedID(ID,aesKey,cipher));
                        rs.updateRow();
                        x++;
                    }
                    dbConnection.commit();
```

ResultSet rs = readID.executeQuery(sql);

I expect the code to connect to any column named CID in the database and then get the strings within the column but instead, I receive the following error...

This plugin has successfully connected to the database...
net.ucanaccess.jdbc.UcanaccessSQLException: UCAExc:::4.0.4 Column not found: CID
    at net.ucanaccess.jdbc.UcanaccessResultSet.getString(UcanaccessResultSet.java:782)
    at Hipaa.main(Hipaa.java:63)
Caused by: net.ucanaccess.jdbc.UcanaccessSQLException: UCAExc:::4.0.4 Column not found: CID
    at net.ucanaccess.jdbc.UcanaccessResultSet.getObject(UcanaccessResultSet.java:649)
    at net.ucanaccess.jdbc.UcanaccessResultSet.getString(UcanaccessResultSet.java:776)
    ... 1 more

Comment: Are you sure that you can connect to a MySQL database using UCanAccess!?!

Answer (score 1):

Try to change this line as :

String sql = "SELECT DISTINCT table_name FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE column_name= 'CID'";

And try to run it again
Hope this will work